# Dynamic SAQL Wave Analytics

Tags: lightning, einstein-analytics, analytics, saql

I'm trying to use IN operator in my SAQL dynamically while doing callout using rest API.

If I'm trying to use hardcoded in operator it’s working.

Working:

```
q = filter q by 'Category' in ["Appliance","Testing"];
```

Not working:

```
'q = filter q by \'Category\' in' + list;
```

I guess it's because the list contains values in single quotes like **['Appliance','Testing']**

Is there a way to automatically convert it to double quotes? Or I need to create it manually

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own list as string:

```
Account accObj = [select Id, GroupData__c from Account where Id = '0014axxxx AAE' limit 1];

List<string> groupList = accObj.GroupData__c.split(';');
List<string> parentGrouping = new List<string>();

for(string str : groupList){
    List<string> subList = str.split(':');
    parentGrouping.add(subList[0]);
}

string stri = '[';
Boolean isFirst = true;
for(string st : parentGrouping){
    if(isFirst){
        stri += '"'+st+'"';
        isFirst = false;
    }else{
        stri += ',"'+st+'"';
    }
}
stri += ']';
system.debug('>>> stri... '+stri);
```